# Plot legend goes out of window while zooming in Matplotlib plot window

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I am using Python 2.7 and plotting using matplotlib package. I have a plot with legend at top. When i try to zoom the plot window to see more information in the plot, sometimes the legend moves out of the window. I am not able to figure out why this happens. This does not happen all the time though. I have attached the code. The lists x11,x22...., temp11,...temp25 and humi11,...humi25 are data from database. The plot is displayed correctly. However i am facing issues with strange situation of legend moving out of plot window. I have also attached the portion of the image for  your reference. Kindly provide your insights.

This is the normal view of the plot.
[image: click here to view].

This is the view of the plot after zooming. See the part of the legend is visible on the corner of window.

[image: click here to view]

Regards

Sriniketh

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt,mpld3
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg importFigureCanvasTkAgg,NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkMessageBox   
from drawnow import *
from Tkinter import *
import  Tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from dateutil.parser import parse
import decimal
plt.subplot(211)
plt.title('Temperatur')
plt.plot((x11), (temp11), 'ro-', label='M1-Node 1')
plt.plot((x12), (temp12), 'go-', label='M1-Node 2')
plt.plot((x13), (temp13), 'bo-', label='M1-Node 3')
plt.plot((x14), (temp14), 'co-', label='M1-Node 4')
plt.plot((x15), (temp15), 'mo-', label='M1-Node 5')
plt.plot((x21), (temp21), 'ro--', label='M2-Node 1')
plt.plot((x22), (temp22), 'go--', label='M2-Node 2')
plt.plot((x23), (temp23), 'bo--', label='M2-Node 3')
plt.plot((x24), (temp24), 'co--', label='M2-Node 4')
plt.plot((x25), (temp25), 'mo--', label='M2-Node 5')

plt.ylabel('Temperatur Grad C')
# plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.985, 0.89),
           bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplot(212)
plt.title('Relativ Luftfeuchtigkeit')
plt.plot((x11), (humi11), 'ro-', label='M1-Node 1')
plt.plot((x12), (humi12), 'go-', label='M1-Node 2')
plt.plot((x13), (humi13), 'bo-', label='M1-Node 3')
plt.plot((x14), (humi14), 'co-', label='M1-Node 4')
plt.plot((x15), (humi15), 'mo-', label='M1-Node 5')
plt.plot((x21), (humi21), 'rd-', label='M2-Node 1')
plt.plot((x22), (humi22), 'gd-', label='M2-Node 2')
plt.plot((x23), (humi23), 'bd-', label='M2-Node 3')
plt.plot((x24), (humi24), 'cd-', label='M2-Node 4')
plt.plot((x25), (humi25), 'md-', label='M2-Node 5')
plt.ylabel('Relativ Luftfeuchtigkeit')
plt.grid(True)
master = var1.get()
plt.suptitle("Temperatur und Luftfeuchtigkeit - %s " % (master))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the legend placement,

```
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.985, 0.89), bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
```

you forgot to specify the location argument. In this case, because you're using figure coordinates, it would make sense to use `loc="upper right"` or `loc=1`:

```
plt.legend(loc=1, bbox_to_anchor=(0.985, 0.89), bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
```

For more insights on how to place the legend out of the plot, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317).